# detail of flush and readline in python

Tags: python, operating-system

run `log.py` befure `follow.py` it works, just like `tail -f`, but run `follow.py` before `log.py` it does NOT work, and if I use vim add something in file, `access-log`, it does NOT work neither.

Why?

Before of `flush` does not write `\0` and after `readline` reading `\0` it does not continue or something else?

what's the details of `flush` and `readline`?

```
# log.py

f = open("access-log","w")

import time, random
while True:
    time.sleep(random.random())
    n = random.randint(0,len(ips)-1)
    m = random.randint(0,len(docs)-1)
    t = time.time()
    date = time.strftime("[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S -0600]",time.localtime(t))
    print >>f,"%s - - %s %s" % (ips[n],date,docs[m])
    f.flush()


# follow.py

import time
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)      # Go to the end of the file
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)    # Sleep briefly
            continue
        yield line

# Example use
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("access-log")
    for line in follow(logfile):
        print line,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `follow.py` first, it opens access-log and continually tries to read something from it.

But then `log.py` comes along and calls `open("access-log", "w")` which *removes* the existing `access-log` file and creates a new one.

Since `follow.py` had the original file open, the operating system maintains a file handle to it, but it isn't the same filename anymore (in fact it has no name at all.)  `follow.py` never knows about the new file that was created, and is stuck reading from the original file handle forever.

Perhaps `log.py` should call open with `"a"` instead of `"w"`?

Comment: Thank you very much